# cs50 initials error with printed output

Tags: c, cs50, edx

I am working on Cs50 pset2 initials. When I run the program it printed out the first 2 letters of the first name and the 2nd, 4th, and 6th letter of the last name. I am wondering if my increment is wrong? Thank you

here is my code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // variables
    string urName;
    char init;
    int i;

    // get user input
    printf("Please state your full name:\n");

    do 
    {
        urName = get_string();
    }
    while (urName == NULL);

    printf("%c", toupper(urName[0]));

    for (i = 0, init = strlen(urName); i < init; i++)
    {
        if ((urName[i]) != '\0')
        { 
            printf("%c", toupper(urName[i+1]));
            i++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the example output..

```
Please state your full name:
den nguyen
DE GYN~/workspace/pset2/ $
```

Comment: Your increments are wrong. You have _two_ increments: one in the `for` loop header, another in the body. You only need one (the first one)..

Comment: Thank you I removed the last increment. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as DYZ mentioned, you increment your counter at **2** instances inside your for-loop:

> ```
> for (i = 0, init = strlen(urName); i < init; i++) // "i" is incremented here
> {
>     if ((urName[i]) != '\0')
>     { 
>         printf("%c", toupper(urName[i+1]));
>         i++; // "i" is also incremented here
>     }
> }
> ```

By incrementing *i* twice, the compiler skips one letter for every iteration of the for-loop. To fix it, you need to remove the `i++` that is inside the for-loop so that only the counter incremental within the for-loop condition is working:

```
for (i = 0, init = strlen(urName); i < init; i++) // "i" only needs to be incremented here
{
    if ((urName[i]) != '\0')
        printf("%c", toupper(urName[i+1]));
}
```

Comment: And since the `init = strlen(urName)` ensures that `urName[i]` won't be a null byte, the inner test is redundant (at the moment).  A modified test will become relevant when the code attempts to detect the initial letter of each word — at the moment, it just converts everything to upper-case.  The code could be: `for (int i = 0; urName[i] != '\0'; i++) { putchar(toupper((unsigned char)urName[i])); }` (which also fixes some other niggly problems — you can reinstate `printf("%c", toupper(…));` if you prefer).

Comment: thank you so much for all the great feedbacks. I will play around with the conditions you offered and clean up my code a little bit. Surprised to see putchar(), I have not learn this function yet so will use it as long as my code passes check50. xD

Comment: @omegaD If my answer worked, please select the checkmark next to my answer. It should turn green when you do so. Thanks!